# Parse XML array into php variables

Tags: php, mysql, xml, arrays

I have an XML feed that is automatically generated on one site and I'm trying to copy it over to another and import the data into a mysql db, but, I'm having difficulty as I'm not familiar with arrays broken down into multiple elements.

Does it get processed the same way a standard array would or does each have to be processed separately? Outputted XML example is included below;

```
[str] => Array
    (
        [0] => 0
        [1] => USD
        [2] => USPS
        [3] => 4228547
        [4] => 486948677
        [5] => 7
        [6] => IndyGen3
        [7] => 1
        [8] => 8 units|8
        [9] => N/A
        [10] => 1
        [11] => Unlimited Refill
        [12] => Unlimited Refill
        [13] => www
        [14] => 1297081
        [15] => unitACTIVE4228547
        [16] => 2
        [17] => 0
        [18] => unit-486948677
        [19] => unit
        [20] => ACTIVE
        [21] => unit
        [22] => 1
        [23] => 1
        [24] => 47d 23h 24m
        [25] => 2013-02-15T19:35:15.153Z
    )

[float] => Array
    (
        [0] => 94.88
        [1] => 94.88
    )

[date] => Array
    (
        [0] => 2013-02-15T19:35:15.438Z
        [1] => 2013-02-15T19:33:14Z
        [2] => 2013-02-15T19:35:02Z
        [3] => 2013-04-04T19:00:00Z
    )

[arr] => Array
    (
        [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
                [@attributes] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => fm_ship_rules
                    )

                [str] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 6,3,25.0,,2013-04-02T19:00:00Z
                        [1] => 6,7,11.95,,2013-03-22T19:00:00Z
                        [2] => 6,15,19.95,,2013-04-02T19:00:00Z
                        [3] => 6,16,19.95,,2013-04-02T19:00:00Z
                    )

            )

        [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
                [@attributes] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => fm_dm_rules_desc
                    )

                [str] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => USPS,USPS Priority, 25.0,,2013-04-02T19:00:00Z
                        [1] => USPS,USPS Two Day,11.95,,2013-03-22T19:00:00Z
                        [2] => USPS,USPS International Priority Puerto Rico,19.95,,2013-04-02T19:00:00Z
                        [3] => USPS,USPS International Priority Canada,19.95,,2013-04-02T19:00:00Z
                    )

            )

    )

[int] => Array
    (
        [0] => 8
        [1] => 8
        [2] => 1
    )
```

)

Comment: I'm not sure what your problem is. Do you don't know how to handle arrays nested in other arrays? Or, don't you know how to create an array from an XML?

Answer (score 1):

To access the information in multidimensional array like the one you have above you would use the following notation. Let's say your main array is called `$arr`.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `mytable`
(
    `currency`,
    `postal_service`,
    `date`,
    `amount_1`,
    `amount_2`
) VALUES (
    '".$arr[str][1]."',
    '".$arr[str][2]."',
    '".$arr[date][0]."',
    '".$arr[float][0]."',
    '".$arr[float][1]."'
)";
```

This is the equivalent of:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `mytable`
(
    `currency`,
    `postal_service`,
    `date`,
    `amount_1`,
    `amount_2`
) VALUES (
    'USD',
    'USPS',
    '2013-02-15T19:35:15.438Z',
    '94.88',
    '94.88'
)";
```